# Override built in required validator of angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I'm making a small web application which contains forms need input validation.
Currently I'm using built-in validator such as: required, minlength, maxlength, ...

I wonder if there is any way to override them or not.
I used the command below for debugging.

```
<span>{{findCategoryBox.controls.name.errors | json}}</span>
```

I received this result:

```
{ "required": true }
```

I want to override the required validator like this:

```
<input class="form-control"
                       placeholder="Category name"
                       formControlName="name"
                       required="CATEGORY_REQUIRED"
                       maxlength="10"
                       minlength="3"/>
```

And I want to receive the result like this:

{ "required": "CATEGORY_REQUIRED"}

How can I do that ?

Please help me

Thank you,